# Im trying to run neovim, but having trouble saving and opening a file

Tags: windows, neovim

I've decided to try out NeoVim for the first time (I have no vim experience). I'm running nvim 0.4.4 on windows 10 and managed to get it installed. I created my init.vim file and strated creating it. I made some changes, then saved with :w and quit with :q. However when I open the same file again I get this message:

> 325: ATTENTION Found a swap file by the name
> "~\AppData\Local\nvim-data\swap\C%%Users%ruy%AppData%Local%nvim%init.vim.swp"
> dated: Wed Apr 28 17:21:08 2021 file name:
> C:\Users\ruy\AppData\Local\nvim\init.vim
> modified: YES
> user name: 0   host name: RUY-PC
> process ID: 7008
> While opening file "C:\Users\ruy\AppData\Local\nvim\init.vim"
> dated: Wed Apr 28 17:47:07 2021
> NEWER than swap file!
> (1) Another program may be editing the same file.  If this is the
> case,                                                     be careful
> not to end up with two different instances of the same
> file when making changes.  Quit, or continue with caution.
> (2) An edit session for this file crashed.
> If this is the case, use ":recover" or "vim -r
> C:\Users\ruy\AppData\Local\nvim\init.vim"
> to recover the changes (see ":help recovery").
> If you did this already, delete the swap file
> "C:\Users\ruy\AppData\Local\nvim-data\swap\C%%Users%ruy%AppData%Local%nvim%init.vim.swp"
> to avoid this message.
> Swap file
> "~\AppData\Local\nvim-data\swap\C%%Users%ruy%AppData%Local%nvim%init.vim.swp"
> already exists!

I don't have file open anywhere else and have quitted nvim. I do manage to open the file, but the message is quite annoying. Any idea whats going on?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems there was a swap file that got lost one time and never deleted. Once I checked the Delete option when opening the problematic file the problem went away.